# Vuex : How to check if an action exists before dispatching it?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting this error : "Unknown local action type..." when I'm dispatching my action, which happens to be in other modules. The action which I'm dispatching does not exist in certain cases. So, I need to apply a condition which will check if this action exists and dispatches the action only if the condition is met. How do I do this ?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below that your actions are already registered. Why do you need to know if it exists then? The error might be caused by incorrectly registering your modules or incorrectly dispatching them. Can you update the question to show your module registration and the dispatch?

Comment: Taking a look at the Vuex source, this message only occurs [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/91f3e69ed9e290cf91f8885c6d5ae2c97fa7ab81/src/store.js#L358), so best guess is you haven't namespaced the module containing the action, or the dispatch call is missing the namespace.

Comment: How to do this in Vuex 4?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem, and here's how I solved it:

```
const methodName = MODULE_NAME + "/" + ACTION_NAME
const actionExists = Object.keys(window.Store._actions).findIndex(key => key === methodName) !== -1

if (actionExists) {
  console.log(methodName + ' exists!')
} else {
  console.log(methodName + ' doesn\'t exists!')
}
```

Comment: How to do this in Vuex 4 inside action?

Answer (score 3):

I do this all the time. @Khasanov72 has it right from outside the store, but you can do it even simpler if you're dispatching an action from another action:

```
//From module action
if (this._actions['module/action']) {
  dispatch('module/action', data)
}
```

Comment: this is not working from inside action. "this" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The only case that I can think of that an action exists only in some cases is when you use [vuex registerModule](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration).

If that the case then you can add a `Boolean` property indicating that the module is registered or not. So in your component:

```
const myModule = () => import('module-path.js')

export default {
  data: () => ({
    isModuleRegistered: false
  }),
  created() {
    myModule.then(module => {
      this.isModuleRegistered = true
      this.$store.registerModule('myModule', module)
      this.$store.dispatch('myModule/someAction')
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    // If you want to unregister it when component gets destroyed
    this.isModuleRegistered && this.$store.unregisterModule('myModule')
  }
}
```

If the snippet above doesn't answers your question or doesn't fit your needs: You have to set a boolean property when you register a module. And then check that boolean to see if the module is registered or not. You have to also change that boolean when the module gets unregistered.

**Note** that above I have lazy loaded the vuex module. If you want to lazy load you vuex modules read [this awesome article](https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-3-lazy-loading-vuex-modules-ed67cf555976) to learn more

Comment: Thanks but this won't solve my problem because my module is already registered. I just need to check if the module has my action or not. I don't know if this verification beforehand is possible or not

Comment: If the module is already registered, how is possible that an action can't be there? Can you provide some code of your module and the code when you dispatch the action?

Comment: for example when using dynamic components in a namespaced system, and one of the namespaces doesn't have the action, i can totally see that happen, and you wouldn't want to hardcode which ones have the actions and shich don't